# webapi MVC4 how to get folder files directory to display data

Tags: file, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, directory

hi guys i able to get the data from my database API. but how do i get the folder files directory example /upload/activity/ ??

```
 public class APIActivityController : ApiController
{
   // var files = db.activities.GetFiles().ToList();
    private istellarEntities db = new istellarEntities();

    public IList<activity2> GetAllCategories()
    {
        IList<activity> lstAct = db.activities.ToList();

        List<activity2> lstReturnList = new List<activity2>();

        foreach (activity a in lstAct)
        {
            Models.activity2 act = new activity2();
            act.ActivityID = a.ActivityID;
            act.ActivityName = a.ActivityName;
            act.Description = a.Description;
            act.ImageURL = a.ImageURL;


            lstReturnList.Add(act);
        }


        return lstReturnList;
    }
   // var files = db.activities.GetFiles().ToList();
    static void DirSearch(string sDir)
```

here is my code, but i am missing something to get the list of directories any help guys?  i know i shouldn't use void, maybe a list instead??

```
 try
   {
       foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
       {
           foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
           {
               Console.WriteLine(f);
           }
           DirSearch(d);
       }
   }
   catch (System.Exception excpt)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the physical folder path of a virtual path from your code like /upload/activity you can use the following code

```
string pathToFiles = Server.MapPath("/upload/activity");
```